# How to create custom image in docker using VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am new to docker, and I'm creating new custom alpine docker image using VSCode. Below is the set of commands I have mentioned on my file(Dockerfile):

```
# Step1 specify the base image
FROM alpine

# Download and install dependencies
RUN apk add --update redis

# Setup the startup command
CMD ["redis-server"]
```

Now, when I am running the docker build command in vs terminal, I am getting an error,

```
PS C:\Users\ankurpandey\Desktop\StudyMaterial\dockerfile-custom> docker build .

[+] Building 0.1s (2/2) FINISHED

 => [internal] load .dockerignore 0.1s
 => transferring context: 2B 0.0s  
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile 0.0s  
 => transferring dockerfile: 2B 0.0s 

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount460459348/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

I have created only one plain file in my root folder dockerfile-custom i.e.,
Dockerfile as shown in the image

[image]

Please suggest me what going wrong with the steps? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you show what is in your .dockerignore please?

Comment: Can you also show all contents of your current working dir (dockerfile-custom) please?

Comment: I have updated the post with the folder structure of working dir. @MetallimaX , I don't have any file with .dockerignore in vscode changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are trying to build a redis-server, the image of redis is already available on docker hub - have you tried that out?

https://hub.docker.com/_/redis

[Check this link - the same issue is discussed and resolved.](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/415)

It seems on windows - if you try

`docker build -f <name of your dockerfile> .`

it should work fine.

Comment: I have tried the above command but it's throwing an error as  
'"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument."

Comment: @AnkurPandey add a '.' at the end to indicate the current directory where the dockerfile is located.

Comment: @vpn -- changing name 'Dockerfile' from 'dockerfile' worked for me. Thanks !!